# Timestamps and database structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to save entries for my app in a way that I can effectively query them by day. I am stuck between two different approaches.
To simplify my problem, let's say I'm making a journal app. For this app, a journal entry contains {title, timestamp}.

Approach #1:

-Journal

--[user_id]

---journal entry

Approach #2

-Journal

--[user_id]

---[Unix timestamp of beginning of day]

----journal entry

As of now, I'm leaning towards approach #1, specifically because it could potentially allow me to grab entries within the last 24 hours by querying rather than for a specific day.

At the same time, however, approach #2 would allow me to more easily handle the potentially sparse amount of entries with client side logic, and it will allow me to avoid using any querying functions. The appeal to me in this approach is that I could just generate very simple functions for generating a timestamp for the beginning of any given day, and I could just get the journal entries childed to that timestamp.

I really want to go with approach #1 as it seems like the right thing to do, and it feels like something that would give me a freedom in many ways that approach #2 would not, but I worry that the querying functions required for part 1 are not very straight forward and would be a huge hastle.

If I go with approach #1, is there a specific way to query?
I'm not sure if using orderbychild(timestamp).startAt(starting timestamp) and .endAt(ending timestamp) would work as it intuitively should, as I've tried this approach in the past and it didn't behave correctly.

Please let me know which approach I should go with, and if it's approach 1, how I should be properly querying it.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to choose.   Store your data in as many different ways as is required by your queries.  If you haven't decided on your queries, then you can't possibly optimize your schema.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to store the timestamp?  it costs nothing and has no impact on queries.  (I've created a utility that just adds createdAt, modifiedAt and the id to every document I save/update.  It can be really helpful in debugging to see these values even if you don't need them for queries.)

Comment: I will definitely do as suggested and store the data in both ways for now. And I know I was vague, but I do also store that type of information for my real models, joelm, and it is indeed incredibly useful to have for every model I have :). Thanks for the advice.